# Why it is returning the date which is not between the range?

Tags: sql-server

I want to only display the data in between 15 to 23 May 2019. But why it is also returning the data which is not between the date range?

Below is my query

```
SELECT Appointment_ID, 
     WO_DespatchName, Despatch_Name AS WO_selectDespatchName,
     FORMAT(Appointment_DateTime, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt') AS Appointment_DateTime, 
     FORMAT(Appointment_ProposalSent, 'dd/MMM/yyyy') AS Appointment_ProposalSent,
     WO_MaidName, Maid_Name AS WO_selectMaidName,
     Appointment_Location, Appointment_FaceToFace, Appointment_Service, Appointment_Remarks, WO_Duration,
     Appointment_ContactID, Contact_Name AS Appointment_selectContactID
     FROM Appointments A
     LEFT JOIN Despatch ON Despatch_ID = WO_DespatchName 
     LEFT JOIN CustomerDetails ON Contact_ID = Appointment_ContactID 
     LEFT JOIN Maid ON Maid_ID = WO_MaidName 
     WHERE FORMAT(Appointment_DateTime, 'dd/MM/yyyy') BETWEEN '15/05/2019' AND '23/05/2019'
     AND (A.IsDelete = 0 OR A.IsDelete IS NULL)
     ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Appointment_DateTime,101)  ASC
```

The output that I get is this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnrSET1V1eoFvEUUtRwXtQmKGWamURgV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thats because you're doing a string compare, not a date compare. Don't format the dates before comparing them.

Comment: because you are comparing the data as string in format `dd/MM/yyyy`. Change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE Appointment_DateTime >= '20190515' AND Appointment_DateTime < '20190524'`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing texts, not dates. So it will return any row where date converted to string starts between 15 and 23.
You need to use date datatype in your comparison:

```
 WHERE Appointment_DateTime >= CAST('20190515' AS date) AND Appointment_DateTime < CAST('20190524' AS date)
```

Please notice I added one day to the end range, so 05/23/2019 11:59:59.9... PM still will be accepted. CAST as date is not necessary, but improves readability.

Comment: It's much better to use a [date format that does not rely on language settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166771/97345), that is, `20190515`. If you do want to use a local format, use `CONVERT` with a value for the third parameter.

Comment: True, I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `where` clause. Since your `Appointment_DateTime` is in `datetime` format. I am expecting that this column has value type `datetime`. 
Now come to your query, `'23/05/2019'` is simple string, so unable to compare this as datetime. First you need to convert your from and to date into `datetime` format.

Please try this (if only date matching is your concern):

```
    SELECT Appointment_ID, 
         WO_DespatchName, Despatch_Name AS WO_selectDespatchName,
         FORMAT(Appointment_DateTime, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt') AS Appointment_DateTime, 
         FORMAT(Appointment_ProposalSent, 'dd/MMM/yyyy') AS Appointment_ProposalSent,
         WO_MaidName, Maid_Name AS WO_selectMaidName,
         Appointment_Location, Appointment_FaceToFace, Appointment_Service, Appointment_Remarks, WO_Duration,
         Appointment_ContactID, Contact_Name AS Appointment_selectContactID
         FROM Appointments A
         LEFT JOIN Despatch ON Despatch_ID = WO_DespatchName 
         LEFT JOIN CustomerDetails ON Contact_ID = Appointment_ContactID 
         LEFT JOIN Maid ON Maid_ID = WO_MaidName 
         WHERE FORMAT(Appointment_DateTime, 'dd/MM/yyyy') BETWEEN FORMAT('15/05/2019', 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND FORMAT('23/05/2019', 'dd/MM/yyyy') 
         AND (A.IsDelete = 0 OR A.IsDelete IS NULL)
         ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Appointment_DateTime,101)  ASC
```

Or you may try `convert` to convert your string into `datetime` format.

Feel free to ask for any further confusion.